# C++ vectors Quicksort - Seems to work differently with different pivots

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

My quicksort algorithm with C++ vectors seem to work fine when I make the pivots as the first, last, or middle element, but not some other values.

I am not sure of all of them, but for example, if I set the pivot as (r-l)/2 it would not sort correctly.

I believe my code is correct, but I am not sure; there might be critical errors.

Is it even possible to sometimes work and sometimes not work, depending on the pivot?

I thought it only affected the running time, so I guess something is wrong with my code.

The following is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int choosePivot(int l, int r) {
    return (r-l)/2; // or Even r/2
}

int partition(vector<int>& vec, int l, int r) {
    int pi = choosePivot(l, r); // pivot index
    int pivot = vec[pi];

    // swap pivot with the beginning
    swap(vec[pi], vec[l]); 

    // beginning index of the right side of the pivot (larger than the pivot)
    int i = l + 1;

    // partition around the pivot
    for (int j = l+1; j <= r; ++j) {
        if (vec[j] <= pivot) {
            swap(vec[i], vec[j]);
            ++i;
        }
    }

    // swap pivot back to its position
    swap(vec[l], vec[i - 1]);

    // return pivot position
    return i - 1;
}

void quicksort(vector<int>& vec, int l, int r) {
    if (l < r) {
        int p = partition(vec, l, r);
        quicksort(vec, l, p - 1);
        quicksort(vec, p + 1, r);
    }
}

int main() {

    ifstream infile("IntegerArray.txt"); 
    int a;
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.reserve(100000);
    while (infile >> a)
        vec.push_back(a);

    quicksort(vec, 0, vec.size() - 1);

    return 0;
}
```

I added a main function that tests the example.

This is the [IntegerArray.txt](https://db.tt/VftBylKA)

It's a file that contains all integers from 1 to 100,000 (no duplicates).

I edited the choosePivot function that it will output a wrongly sorted array.

I don't have a print because the size is too big.

Comment: Does your median3 indeed compare _indices_ and not _values_ in the array?

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of the problem, as opposed to code that might, under unspecified circumstances, be incorrect in some unspecified way?

Comment: Please read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then add the missing information.

Comment: @Gassa Yes I am sure that it only compares indices.

Comment: Please show us, how a wrong result looks like. That'd help to decide on the type of bug.

Comment: Check your pivot - `(r-l)/2` may be less than `l`, and pay heed to Gassa's comment about `median3()`.

Comment: @greybeard To further state my question: Is it possible that the sorting output can be wrong when the algorithm is correct, for quicksort? Does the output depend on what pivot I choose? Because I thought you can use any pivot since we even have a random version.

Comment: An implementation's result _should not_ depend on the choice of pivot _value_. What do you expect to happen if `pi < l` to `r < pi`?.

Comment: @JaeMinJimmyShin that's _bad_, the median-of-three is supposed to be the median of three _values_, not _indices_. Otherwise, there is no point in it: as long as `l` < `(l + r) / 2` < `r`, we know the median _index_ already.

Comment: As others have stated, the algorithm is _not_ correct. In `choosePivot`, for example, you probably meant `return (l+r)/2;`.

Comment: @Gassa Oh i see what the problem was. But anyway Thank you guys. I thought  the pivot didnt affect the result, but it definitely should.

Comment: Seriously.. why the downvote? If a newbie can't ask questions at a community, what does the community exist for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way quicksort is implemented in the code above, it breaks when the pivot index is not between `l` and `r`.
In such case, it starts by bringing in a value from outside the [l, r] segment with `swap(vec[pi], vec[l]);`.
This can break an already-sorted part of the array.

Now, `(r-l)/2` is not always between `l` and `r`.
When, for example, `l = 10` and `r = 20`, the pivot index is `(20-10)/2 = 5`.
So, the code will start sorting the [10, 20] segment by swapping `vec[5]` and `vec[10]`.
If the part with `vec[5]` was sorted before [10, 20] segment, this will most likely result in the array not being sorted in the end.

Comment: Oh now i understand !! So this was the problem, not the code.